# Background Image should rezise to div inside

Tags: css, background, background-image, image-resizing, autoresize

I am trying to create a background image with a smaller div inside with text in it. Right now, it works great on desktop, but as the screen size gets smaller, the div with the text goes over the background image.

I would like the image to resize automatically in these cases.

```css
#cb_1 {
  background-image: url("https://www.randnotizen.org/wp-content/uploads/full/0019-Elektrotechnik-Platine-Bauteile.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#cb_1 h1 {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#cb_1 h3 {
  color: #356651;
}

#cb_1 p {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#cb_1 article {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 45%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

button.default {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #356651;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section id="cb_1">
  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <h3>
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="default">Stet clita kasd</button>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi there. You've included a **relative path** for the image in your code. Could you please upload your image online, and update your code to link to the online version? We aren't able to see your local image, and it's important to be able to see the problematic image in order to help solve this problem :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using a Placeholder myself at the moment. 
Try using this pictutre - it's about the same size:
https://www.randnotizen.org/wp-content/uploads/full/0019-Elektrotechnik-Platine-Bauteile.jpg

Comment: On your `#cb_1` add `background-size: cover;` think this is what you're looking for. I'll post answer if Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Absolute positioning removed for `#cb_1 article` and added `background-size: cover`, `height: 100vh` for the image container.

```css
#cb_1 {
  background-image: url("https://www.randnotizen.org/wp-content/uploads/full/0019-Elektrotechnik-Platine-Bauteile.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#cb_1 h1 {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#cb_1 h3 {
  color: #356651;
}

#cb_1 p {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#cb_1 article {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 45%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

button.default {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #356651;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section id="cb_1">
  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <h3>
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="default">Stet clita kasd</button>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `background-size:100% 100%;` in `@media` responsive code inside `#cb_1` and fix your width and padding according screen inside `#cb_1 article`

```css
*{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#cb_1 {
  background-image: url("https://www.randnotizen.org/wp-content/uploads/full/0019-Elektrotechnik-Platine-Bauteile.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#cb_1 h1 {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#cb_1 h3 {
  color: #356651;
}

#cb_1 p {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#cb_1 article {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 45%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

button.default {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #356651;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
 #cb_1 {
  background-image: url("https://www.randnotizen.org/wp-content/uploads/full/0019-Elektrotechnik-Platine-Bauteile.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}

#cb_1 article{ width:100%; padding:20px; top:50px;}

}
```

```html
<section id="cb_1">
  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <h3>
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="default">Stet clita kasd</button>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```